# What can be synced between Sharepoint and MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I'd like to know what can be synced between Sharepoint and MS Project and if any certain permissions are needed (for either Sharepoint or MS Project) to do this? I have not used any of these programs but researching for my boss.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question. First, there is project server and there is ms project, and the options are different, depending on which product you're talking about. As for ms project itself, here are the docs that cover the functionality of syncing with a SharePoint task list:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-with-a-sharepoint-tasks-list-fb956d2c-723d-4d5a-b7e5-710ef82aa27a

Comment: Thanks for this, Mike. I realize it's broad but this is all the info she gave me. Would you be able to share any similar documentation for project server and how that would work with sharepoint? Also, would you happen to know if you need a particular Sharepoint permission to allow syncing?

Comment: Project server is a Sharepoint application, so any content uploaded to Project Server is already in SharePoint, so perhaps no syncing is necessary. Some shops already have  content in SP and then implement PS, and they ask about syncing. In those cases, I recommend they learn how to use PS before committing to that sort of thing. (PS is a big tool with extra licensing. The functionality is fantastic, but it should not be implemented on a whim).